# How to set root proxy settings via command line?

Tags: 12.04, server, sudo, proxy

I am using fabric to deploy a project and have run into an issue:

fabric does not currently (as far as I'm aware) have the ability to specify options to it sudo command, therefore I cannot use `sudo -E` to use the local users proxy settings.

How can I go about setting the proxy settings for root.

This needs to be via command line as I'm working on a server box withou a GUI.

Comment: did you try setting it in the sudo command in the fabfile? fabric should still invoke the command with bash -c. something like this on the server:  sudo bash -c 'http_proxy=proxyserver blah'

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can help you but I use `tsocks` for socks proxies like `Tor`

Install the latest version of tor and tsocks `sudo apt-get install tor tsocks`

Edit the tsocks configuration file `sudo gedit /etc/tsocks.conf` so the last few lines should be :

```
server = 127.0.0.1
# Server type defaults to 4 so we need to specify it as 5 for this one
server_type = 5
# The port defaults to 1080 but I've stated it here for clarity 
server_port = 9050
```

and execute any command with tor proxy `tsocks sudo apt-get update` for example .

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference' sake. `Fabric` perfectly allows the `sudo` command. From [the docs](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.sudo)

```
fabric.operations.sudo(command, shell=True, pty=True, combine_stderr=None, user=None, quiet=False, warn_only=False, stdout=None, stderr=None, group=None)
```

Here is the example from the docs.

```
sudo("~/install_script.py")
sudo("mkdir /var/www/new_docroot", user="www-data")
sudo("ls /home/jdoe", user=1001)
result = sudo("ls /tmp/")
with settings(sudo_user='mysql'):
    sudo("whoami") # prints 'mysql'
```

By the way, nice you are using Fabric. It is a good deployment tool.